# is there any way to force mybatis to use setter

Tags: java, mybatis, mybatis-generator, mybatis-mapper

I need to do some logic before the value is set from the db with mybatis,
however, my list field always has size=0

[image]

i really need help, if someone knows please help me,
I'm so appreciative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyBatis is calling your setter. But it works differently than you might be thinking.

This is the way it works - MyBatis will create an empty list and set it in your POJO. Then, for each row, MyBatis will call `getRoleList().add()` to fill out the list row by row. MyBatis does not create an internal list of values and then call `setRoleList()` with a fully populated list.

It is best to use MyBatis objects as simple POJOs. Any other processing should be completed after the objects are returned from MyBatis.